# How to have app use a private .php webpage?

Tags: php, security, http, httpwebrequest, bots

I want my desktop app to hit a `.php` page on my web site.  The `.php` page will perform a server side task and will return an HTTP response indicating success/failure etc.

How can I ensure only my desktop app will be able to access the `.php` page?  How can I prevent bots, crawlers and hackers from accessing the page?

Should I have a random phrase in the URL? eg:

```
http://www.website.com/s3g8k0d1q6/myphpfile.php
```

Comment: Use Public & Private Encryption .... Puck on the desktop .. private on your server .....

Comment: @Baba: have you got a ref for this?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way would be to have basic password checking.  Assuming by "hit" you mean`POST`, put this at the top of your PHP:

```
if($_POST["password"] !== 12345) { header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");die(); }
```

This'll return your generic 404 unless it's your desktop app sending the correct password.

([*Please* don't use](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6iW-8xPw3k) `12345`, that's just an example)

Comment: OK, I assume that SSL is required for this otherwise the password would be sent in clear text in the POST request?

Comment: It depends on how secure you're talking.  You can use SSL, but this doesn't require it.

Comment: But if SSL is not used then the POST request would contain the password in clear text, wouldn't it?

Comment: Correct, it won't stop a dedicated hacker.  Your question only mentions bots/crawlers, etc, which won't be able to see the POST from your app.

Comment: @CJ7 Are you worried about bots or dedicated hackers?

Comment: @CJ7, This answer should work for you. And why don't you encrypt and send the POST field at one end, and decrypt at the other end? At least it'll secure it more than leaving it clear text.

Comment: @ArjunAbhynav: won't an SSL connection encrypt everything anyway?

Comment: @SomeKittens: if the `.php` file has global read permissions, won't the file and therefore the password be readable to the world?

Comment: @CJ7 If you give the world FTP access, yes.  Otherwise, no.  You can't read PHP in a browser like you can JS/HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop applications that access a web service require an application key. That application key is then used to make requests to the web service. Each application gets it's own randomly generated key when the user registers it, or the desktop application can do this process silently in the background.

How you authenticate the user/desktop application so that an application key is provided is up to you. It could be an email/password pair, or a secret key that only the desktop application knows, or a key that is emailed to each user that allows them to activate the desktop application.

The keys are stored in a database, and you could add an extra column to the table to indicate if the key has been revoked.

You can use SSL to help keep the application key a secret.

How the key is passed to the service doesn't really matter. It could be a $_GET, $_POST or part of the Http header. PHP supports features to extract details from all those methods.

Once you get a request in say $_POST['key'] you would check the database to see if that key exists, and isn't revoked. If found, then you would perform the request or provide some other response.

For the notice PHP user be sure to protect against SQL injection attacks. Here is a quick sample code, but not tested.

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['key']))
{
   $con = mysql_connect('localhost','mathew','1234') or die("can't open db");
   mysql_select_db('my_db',$con);
   $key = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['key']);
   $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Keys WHERE Revoked = 0 AND Key = '$key'");
   if(!empty(mysql_fetch_array($result)))
   {
       // perform web service here
   }
}
```

This would be the simplest approach, and provide basic security if performed using SSL. If you don't have SSL, then someone could sniff the key, but it depends if your application is something *worth* spending the time to hack.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a robots.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: myfile.php
```

Granted, it won't prevent malicious bots or bots who otherwise ignore the robots.txt file, but legitimate bots such as search engine crawlers will likely be dissuaded.

Comment: Sorry to download vote, but this provides zero security which is what the question was asking for.

Comment: @Mathew For clarification, it didn't ask for security at the time of the post.

Comment: Sorry, nothing incorrect with your answer. It just doesn't answer the question.